# Open MPI error when setting up a cluster with more than 3 hosts

Tags: c, linux, openmpi

We cannot run a program in a [Open MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org) cluster with more than 3 machines.

If we run:

```
mpirun --host master,slave5,slave3 ./cluster
```

it works.

If we run:

```
mpirun --host master,slave4,slave3,slave5 ./cluster
```

We get the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname slave5: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Despite of the fact that it looks like a name resolution error, it is not, because slave5 works on the first command.

We've seen other people reporting the same error without any solution so far. Example:

- http://users.open-mpi.narkive.com/LECsvO1e/ompi-users-cannot-run-a-job-with-more-than-3-nodes

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you setup correctly /etc/hosts files (or DNS) on every host (post all 4 files here)? Can every host ping every other host when `ping` is used with name of target host (this is which `hostname` command at target host returns)?

Comment: The first response in the mailing list thread you linked provides a workaround.  Does that solve the problem for you?

Comment: This problem is very common as I see on some forum take a look here https://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.open-mpi.org/msg29784.html
but idont think this would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is likely because Open MPI defaults to a tree-based spawn, meaning that it ssh's from node A to node B, and then ssh's from node B to node C.  See https://blogs.cisco.com/performance/tree-based-launch-in-open-mpi and https://blogs.cisco.com/performance/tree-based-launch-in-open-mpi-part-2 for more details.

Hence, if if you disable the tree-based spawn (via "mpirun --mca plm_rsh_no_tree_spawn 1" -- which will cause all ssh's to occur from node A), your launch will work as expected.

However, the better solution is to make all your cluster machine names resolvable from all machines.  E.g., when you can run something like this successfully, then Open MPI's launch should work successfully:

```html
foreach node (Node1 Node2 Node3 Node4 ...)
    foreach other (Node1 Node2 Node3 Node4 ...)
        echo from $node to $other
        ssh $node ssh $other hostname
```

Comment: I have a cluster of 72 nodes and "mpirun --mca plm_rsh_no_tree_spawn 1" worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: does this --mca plm_rsh_no_tree_spawn 1 slows down the application?

Comment: It may slow down the *launch* of the application (depending on how many servers you are launching across -- the tree spawn is beneficial as the number of nodes increases).  But it has no effect on MPI communications.